# Training MNIST dataset with Sigmoid Activation function

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, neural-network, mnist

According to [this tutorial](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/), with `Python` and `Numpy`, I want to train `MNIST` dataset to a neural network that can recognize handwritten digits. I understand the logic but i have a problem right now.

In this tutorial test case was `AND` logical gate and because of small amount of data, it works fine. But I'm using `MNIST` database and each image has `28*28` dimension,And when I convert each of them to a vector, I have `N*784` matrix. And if I have a `784*1` matrix as `weight matrix`, When I multiply it with the input matrix, The resulting numbers is going to be very small or very large numbers(Negative or Positive) and because i use `Sigmoid` activation function, all of my data divided in to two section, 1 and 0 at first learning cycle, But i need small numbers that converging slowly.

for example i get these numbers after multiplication: `-569.87541502` , `218.62477264` and the first one is 0 in `Sigmoid` activation function and the second is 1, And there is no room for training and converging. All of this because of large amount of data that summation of them resulting to this large or very small numbers.

I use this trick for generating very small weights than the original tutorial but i get the same results(I was thinking because these are small numbers, summation of them can't be very large but i get the same results):

```
syn0 = (2*np.random.random((784,10))-1)*(0.00000005-0.00000001) + 0.00000001
```

I don't know how i can overcome to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solutions:

#### Make sure to preprocess your input.

If your input pixels are in range [0, 255], it's better to rescale them into [0.0, 1.0]. This suffices in most situation.

A more advanced way would be using [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).

#### Make sure you initialize weight matrices in a normalized fashion.

By normalized, I mean each of the 784-dimension column vector of the weight matrix should have a fixed L2-norm. For a simple setup, you could just normalize them to 1.

Weight matrix initialization is a research topic, for example using [glorot initialization](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) tend to show better results for deep networks.

Comment: There is no any python implementation of glorot initialization?

Comment: @Fcoder It's simple, just multiply column  vector by `sqrt(6./(in_dims+out_dims))`

Comment: Thank you, what you mean in_dims and out_dims? right now i create weight matrix via random method. What's your solution, i cant understand. i'm new to this topics, sorry for much questions.

Comment: @Fcoder Input and output dimensions of a particular layer, just column/row dimensions of weight matrix in this particular case. The goal is to initialze with standard normal dist then rescale.

Comment: Thanks, i do this: syn0 = np.dot(syn0, np.sqrt(6./(7840+59580))) . but again, when i multyply inputs with weights i get large numbers that all of them in sigmoid function is 1 or 0 and networks cant learn anything. numbers like this:  77998.9275072 ,  -81295.10915719 , -78033.05164159

Comment: @Fcoder Just try `syn0 /= 28.`, the simplest normalization.